# Sending json data as raw-json not working - postman

Tags: json, api, multidimensional-array, postman

I'm trying to make a post-call API of Callpicker following these instructions:
[image]

I tried to make the post-call as JSON but it shows this error:
[raw_json_picture][1]

**JSON CODE**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q2Ad.png

```
{
    "token": "1d7af606e28caa8321bbdfe9c58cf0900b4c114977141645687dd6e4c697aa605bebaa36aeb5233b9764fc0f68cd670930792c83caa173f775b4491ae2435e0c",
    "datetime": "now",
    "first_call": "{'destination_type':'Extension','destination_id':'201539'}",
    "second_call": "{'destination_type':'Phone','destination_id':'4731938483'}",
    "preferred_trunk": "524831115864"
}
```

Also, I tried another way and made the post-call like this:

**Header**
[image]
**Body**
[image]
But it didn't work either ... I don't know what is wrong

I appreciate your help! thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not form-data, it's raw-json.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your API and use the application/json Content-Type when setting the first_call and second_call parameter in the form-data. It worked!

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure we need to pass token variable in the body? usually that goes into header. Let me try again and get back to you.

Comment: @Blaz I have updated the answer, please upvote as well.